# Reading from a generic USB HID interface in Debian?

Tags: usb, debian, hid

I have a USB HID interface that reads DTMF and CallerId from the telephone line. It works in Win32 but I really need a port to Debian.

When it's plugged in dmesg shows it as 'new full speed USB device' and 'generic-usb  input, hiddev96 etc'.( I suspect that most of this is generic output from dmesg.)  I can find it under /dev as usb/hiddev0 and input/event1 and by-id, by-path, etc

In any event, Im wondering if there is some equivalent to 'hyperterm' on windows that might let me see the output.

Answer (score -1):

I would try:

```
less -f /dev/hiddev0
```

or

```
sudo less -f /dev/hiddev0
```

Alternatives:

```
cat /dev/hiddev0
tail -f /dev/hiddev0
od -x /dev/hiddev0 | less
```